# Group rows with same name only under certain conditions with SQL in redshift

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift

Now I have a table with webpage data look like this:

```
 Visitor_ID  Visit_ID  visit_time  pagepath         page seq    timestart        timeend
   0001       0111      2018-11-19  /homepage          1         ...              ...
   0001       0111      2018-11-19  /someotherpage     2         ...              ...
   0001       0111      2018-11-19  /product           3     2018-11-19 23:05  2018-11-19 23:15
   0001       0111      2018-11-19  /product           4     2018-11-19 23:15  2018-11-19 23:16
   0001       0111      2018-11-19  /product           5     2018-11-19 23:16  2018-11-19 23:17
   0001       0111      2018-11-19  /someotherpage     6         ...              ...   
   0001       0111      2018-11-19  /someotherpage     7         ...              ...  
   0001       0111      2018-11-19  /product           8     2018-11-19 23:25  2018-11-19 23:26
```

There is an error in the raw data, that some of the pages are duplicated, and what I want is to group the duplication, which is in sequence like the pages sequence 3,4,5 and sum up the time browse like:

```
 Visitor_ID  Visit_ID  visit_time  pagepath   page seq     timestart        timeend
   0001       0111      2018-11-19  /product      3     2018-11-19 23:05  2018-11-19 23:17
   ...
   ...
   0001       0111      2018-11-19  /product      8     2018-11-19 23:25  2018-11-19 23:26
```

I used the group by and take the minumum. However the problem is, in this case, page 8 is a vaild visit and it will also be grouped, which is not the desired result

I also tried to use lag and partition solution, but the problem is

- I can just get the row after
- And the number of replication is different between record, so cannot solve it by fixed code

In overall is, I want to group the record that with the same pagepath which is on sequence and sum them up, but at the same time keep the same pagepath which is not a duplicated record. Does anyone have any idea how to do so in redshift?

Many thanks for your help in advance

Comment: `...` *(ellipses)* usually mean "carry on the same pattern as above".  This makes your example look like rows 6 and 7 are also for `/product`.  I recommend you put in a different value *(like `/smeg`)* to make it explicit and clear that those are not the `/product`) lines.

Comment: what is the logic that you make use of to determine that record 8 is a valid page visit where as records 3-7 is a duplicate(is it non-overlapping records ie timeend and timestart are contiguous?

Comment: Please also give the code you've tried, such as with `LAG()`, and show the results you got, why they're wrong, and what you want it to do differently.  Reading this may help you clarify your question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph - If you read it again, and read my comment, I'm quietly confident that the OP ***meant*** to say that only 3, 4, 5 are duplicates, and that 6, 7 are something completely different.  Which made using `...` a very confusing bad idea.

Comment: @MatBailie Yes, you are right. Column 6,7 is sth different and it just aim for illustrate the row 8, which have the same value but it should be regarded as valid.
BTW, many thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph It is because the table should be in page scope. Thta means the page should not exist multiple times in a row, so that's why it should be regarded as abnormal. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in your post `...` means "and here is something different" *(as opposed to the actual meaning of "here is more of the same")* then you appear to want a "gaps-and-islands" solution.

I'll post the answer, you see if it works.  But the explanation is long-winded and you'll need to search SO for other `gaps-and-islands` answers to find various explanations.

```
SELECT
  Visitor_ID,
  Visit_ID,
  MIN(visit_time)  AS visit_time,
  pagepath,
  MIN(page_seq)    AS page_seq,
  MIN(timestart)   AS timestart,
  MAX(timeend)     AS timeend
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Visitor_ID, Visit_ID, pagepath
                           ORDER BY page_seq
                      )
                         AS pagepath_seq
  FROM
    yourTable
)
  AS sequenced
GROUP BY
  Visitor_ID,
  Visit_ID,
  pagepath,
  pagepath_seq - page_seq
```

*(Makes the assumption that `page_seq` starts at 1, never has any gaps, and "restarts" for each Visitor_ID/Visit_ID.)*

Example : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=1d47a59b33bbfae11ba3040f392ec9c5